# Mixed random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

On Barry James'book of probability there is an example of a mixed random variable on page 43. He takes the random variable  $Y=min (X,1/2) $, where  $X $ is the uniform distribution onde  $(0,1) $. How can I obtain the distribution function of  $Y $?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $P(Y \leq y)=P(Y \leq y \mid X \geq 1/2) P(X \geq 1/2)+P(Y \leq y \mid X<1/2) P(X<1/2)$. Now take cases depending on whether $y<1/2$ or not.

Comment: Conditioning is unnecessary (and might only cloud things).

Comment: @Did I did it because $Y$ has one familiar distribution when $X \geq 1/2$ and another when $X<1/2$. It's not necessary but it's not a bad idea either.

Answer (score 0):

**Comment:** In case it's not obvious to OP by now (2 days later), @Ian's Answer does it;
$Y$ has a mixture of 50% $Unif(0,1/2)$ and 50% constant 1/2.
The following empirical CDF plot of 2000 simulated values
closely imitates the actual CDF.

[image]